# Positioning an alert banner on top of page when the rest of the content is an iframe

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating an alert banner with Angular 7, this banner has to be always on top of the page, I could do that with `position: fixed` and `z-index: 999`, but when user scrolls, the banner comes along, I would like to remove this behavior and make it stick on the top of the page but I couldn't make it work because the rest of my page is an i-frame.

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <iframe
        name="ci"
        id="custom_iframe"
        allowfullscreen="true"
        *ngIf="formUrl"
        allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; midi *; encrypted-media *;"
        #iframe
    ></iframe>
</div>
```

my css code

```
#banner{
    position: fixed;
    float: initial;
    z-index: 999;
    width:1900px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

example on the page (already scrolled to the bottom)

[image: I want the blue rectangle to stay on top of the page without coming along when user scrolls]

The problem here is probably because the iframe has an entirely other context, meaning it's css does not know my banner exists, but I have no idea on what should I do to make it work.

Comment: Whats about to add the notification to the DOM of the iframe-content?

Comment: you mean appending my banner within the iframe (as an element of the iframe)?

Comment: yes; iframe.contentDocument.append(yourNode)

Comment: why don't you use position absolute if you want it to scroll with the rest? https://jsfiddle.net/fwvc1xyq/